# When selenium standalone jar is required?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, selenium, automation

I was trying to do a demo project in eclipse for selenium testing. While running it was giving me some error : NoClassFoundError com/google/.. When I added selenium standalone jar it worked find. But in my another selenium project I have not added selenium standalone jar , just selenium 2.40 jar then also it is working fine. so I want to know when standalone jar is required?

Answer (score 0):

Reasons to use Selenium standalone server:

- you want to use Selenium RC (known as Selenium 1.0);
- you want to use Grid to run your tests in parallel mode;
- you want to use Remote WebDriver.

In case you want to use only WebDriver API you only need to use selenium-.jar and corresponding driver (eg. chromedriver). Using WebDrier API you send commands to browser directly without injecting JS like Selenium RC does.

**Edited.**

More details are in official documentation: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp